# Directx Backbuffer capturing

Tags: memory, graphics, directx, capture, directx-9

i want to capture my Directx screen from backbuffer to memory address by using "memcpy" function.
so i wrote this codes:

```
int ScreenWidth =1024;
int ScreenHeight =768;
int BITSPERPIXEL =32; // XRGB

BYTE* pBits ;
IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;

pBits=new BYTE[ScreenWidth*ScreenHeight * 4 ]; //1024 x 768 x 4 for XRGB

pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ScreenWidth , ScreenHeight ,
                                          D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, 
                                          &pSurface, NULL);

pd3dDevice->GetBackBuffer(0,0,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE::D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface);      


D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
pSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect,NULL,
                   D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE|
                   D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK|D3DLOCK_READONLY);
for( int i=0 ; i < ScreenHeight ; i++)
{
    memcpy( (BYTE*) pBits + i * ScreenWidth * BITSPERPIXEL / 8 , 
        (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits + i* lockedRect.Pitch , 
        ScreenWidth * BITSPERPIXEL / 8);
}
pSurface->UnlockRect();
```

but when program run i got this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x58b6be20 (msvcr100d.dll) in SimpleSample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

and program break on this line :

```
 memcpy( (BYTE*) pBits + i * ScreenWidth * BITSPERPIXEL / 8 , 
        (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits + i* lockedRect.Pitch , 
        ScreenWidth * BITSPERPIXEL / 8);
```

it sames lockedRect.pBits or lockedRect.Pitch address mem was not create ....
what u think?
please help me to solve this problem.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use D3DMEM_POOL? Are you sure that backbuffer format X8A8R8B8?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find the answer for the same. From some sources I am able to figure out that there back buffers are application specific. i.e. they write data on the back buffer bound to them.

I am trying to figure out where the first parameter in the GetBackBuffer() plays role? It's iSwapChain. MSDN help is little.